# buenas, tengo problemas tratando de mostrar los resultados='0' de SUM en la vista que se me pide, intente de la forma normal sin excepcionar los null

Tags: sql, sum

[image]

Crear una vista que muestre el Nombre del Cliente y el monto total de compras que realizó (Total Compras). Mostrar el resultado de la vista ordenada por nombre del Cliente. Incluir en el resultado a aquellos clientes que no tengan compras registradas, mostrando en la columna total en este caso el valor CERO

Esto es lo que intente pero no me bota los datos de los que tienen total `compras=0`por favor si podrían resolver mi duda. ¿Qué debo hacer?

```sql
SELECT C.Nombre as Nombre_Cliente, 
 
 sum(CD.cantidad * CD.precioUnitario)as Total_Compras

FROM Cliente C ,Compra Co RIGHT OUTER JOIN 

CompraDetalle CD ON Co.CompraID=CD.CompraID

WHERE C.ClienteID=Co.ClienteID

GROUP BY C.Nombre

ORDER BY C.Nombre
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar cambiar el tipo de union. Lo importante son los clientes, por tanto las otras tablas van después con un Left Join. Si la suma de estas columnas para el cliente no retorna valor, entonces utilizas una función para reconvertir esa ausencia en un 0

```
Create table Cliente (clienteId int, nombre varchar(100))
Create table Compra (CompraId int, ClienteId int)
Create table CompraDetalle (CompraDetalleId int, CompraId int, cantidad int, precioUnitario int)
```

Llenamos con Datos:

```
Insert into Cliente(clienteId, nombre) Values (1,'Ana');
Insert into Cliente(clienteId, nombre) Values (2,'Eva');
Insert into Cliente(clienteId, nombre) Values (3,'Carlos');

Insert into Compra (CompraId,ClienteId)Values (1,1),(2,1),(3,2);

Insert into CompraDetalle(CompraDetalleId, CompraId, cantidad, precioUnitario) Values (1,1,10,10);
Insert into CompraDetalle(CompraDetalleId, CompraId, cantidad, precioUnitario) Values (2,1,10,20);
Insert into CompraDetalle(CompraDetalleId, CompraId, cantidad, precioUnitario) Values (3,2,25,25);
Insert into CompraDetalle(CompraDetalleId, CompraId, cantidad, precioUnitario) Values (4,2,100,100);
Insert into CompraDetalle(CompraDetalleId, CompraId, cantidad, precioUnitario) Values (5,3,100,100);
Insert into CompraDetalle(CompraDetalleId, CompraId, cantidad, precioUnitario) Values (6,3,100,100);
```

Nota: Los tipos de datos, han sido escogidos por simpleza.

Ahora tenemos a 3 clientes, 2 con compras varias.

**Solución:**

```
SELECT C.Nombre as Nombre_Cliente, 
     ISNULL(sum(CD.cantidad * CD.precioUnitario),0) as Total_Compras

FROM Cliente C LEFT JOIN Compra  Co on C.ClienteID=Co.ClienteID
               LEFT JOIN CompraDetalle CD ON Co.CompraID=CD.CompraID
GROUP BY C.Nombre
ORDER BY C.Nombre;
```

[image: RESULTADO]